# Django Middleware to log every time a user hits a page

Tags: python, django, middleware

As the title states I am trying to create a middleware that will record every time a user hits a page.

Here's my model.py I'll be working with:

```
class UserPageTracking(models.Model):
    """ Page hits with user info """
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(db_column='USER_ID', max_length=8, default="")
    url = models.URLField(db_column='URL')
    date_visited = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DATE_VISITED', auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'page_views'
```

Here's what's in my middleware:

```
from .models import UserPageTracking


class UserPageTrackingMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        user_id = request.user.username
        # not every request will have a http_referer, so when it doesn't just ignore it and don't save anything
        to_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        if to_url:

            user_page_tracking = UserPageTracking.objects.create(
                 url=to_url, user_id=user_id
            )
            user_page_tracking.save()
        return response
```

my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'app.middleware.user.UserMiddleware',
    'app.middleware.user_page_tracking.UserPageTrackingMiddleware'
]
```

This works alright the only issue is every time I load a page/go to a page it'll hit this middleware multiple times (at least twice, sometimes like 3 or 4). When I check the db I'll have 3 - 4 entries that are a about 40 - 50 ms apart from each other.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this something I can't do via middleware and I have to do something else to log user activity.

Comment: Have you registered it for than once ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question

Comment: Have you added it in settings for more than once inside MIDDLEWARE ?

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your settings file.

Comment: Yes it is registered, and it's the last item in the MIDDLEWARE list

Comment: Why are you logging the referrer, wouldn't it make more sense to log the current request path: `request.path`? You could have multiple XHR/media requests all originating from one page and they would all have the same referrer