# Empty `request.user.username` while handling a GET request created

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I was trying out logging all URLs accessed by user along with user id and date time when it was accessed using django middleware as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081706/django-middleware-to-log-every-time-a-user-hits-a-page).

For some URLs it was not logging user id. I checked and found that the `request.user.username` was empty string. I checked views corresponding to those URL and found that those views did not have desired decorators. For example, I changed this:

```
def getXyz_forListView(request):
    # view body ...
```

to this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,])
def getXyz_forListView(request):
    # view body ...
```

and it started working.

However some views are created from classes:

```
class XyzView(View):  
    
    def get(self, request):
        # view body ...
```

I added same decorators:

```
class XyzView(View):  
    
    @api_view(['GET'])
    @authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,])
    def get(self, request):
        # view body ...
```

But it is still not working. What I am missing?

**PS:**

It is added to `urls.py` as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^xyz/', XyzView.as_view(), name="xyz"),
]
```

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to inherit from APIView class:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).